# All section toggle issue in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, toggle

I am trying to add Read More read less feature. The issue I am facing is when I click on the toggle button it shows more content for all the workers. Please have a look and help me figure out where I am going wrong.

```
                 <ul>
                  <li v-for="item in worker.services.slice(0, 2)">
                    {{ item}}
                  </li>                     
                  <div class="body" v-show="showSection">
                    <li v-for="item in worker.services">
                      {{ item}}
                    </li>
                  </div>
                  <button @click="toggle">Toggle</button>  
                </ul>

<script>
methods: {
    toggle() {
      this.showSection = !this.showSection
    }
  },
  data: () => ({
      workers: [],
      showSection: false
    }
  }
})

</script>




<button @click="toggle(worker.id)">{{showSection?'read less':'...'}}</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using worker.id to identify which worker's section to expand:

```
<div class="body" v-show="showSection === worker.id">
  <li v-for="item in worker.services.slice(2)">
    {{ item}}
  </li>
</div>
```

and

```
<button @click="toggle(worker.id)">Toggle</button>
```

and

```
<script>
methods: {
    toggle(workerId) {
      if (this.showSection === workerId) {
        this.showSection = null
      } else {
        this.showSection = workerId
      }
    }
  },
```

Comment: This is not the issue. The issue is there are multiple lawyers on the page and each with multiple services. When I click on the toggle button all the workers show all the services instead of the particular lawyer on whose toggle button I click

Comment: In that case, just make the variable `showSectionsForLawyers` and make it an array/set of lawyer identifiers. If contained show. When toggling, if contained remove, otherwise add.

Comment: Actually this is what is happening worker.services. And I am sorry I misspelled it is workers. The issue is when I click on the toggle it should show all the services of that particular worker on whose toggle button I click but it toggles for all the workers.

Comment: Yes, I understand. I'm suggesting that the rendering does something like:
`<div class="body" v-show="showSectionsForLawyers.includes(lawyerId)">`.

If you can only expand one lawyer at at time, it can be simpler:
`<div class="body" v-show="showSectionsForLawyer === lawyerId">`.

Comment: I tried it the way you suggested but it doesn't work. The button gets disabled. I tried <div class="body" v-show="showSectionsForWorker === workerId">

Comment: I just made up `workerId` I don't know how you identify different workers, maybe `worker.id`? It also means that clicking toggle has to set/unset `showSectionsForWorker` using `worker.id` rather than `true/false`.

Comment: I updated the answer assuming `worker.id` is what's used. If you don't have a unique worker identifier an index could also be used where the `for ... workers` logic happens.

Comment: if I do something like this on the button <button @click="toggle(worker.id)">{{showSection?'read less':'...'}}</button> it still works but the issue is if I click on ... on any particular worker the button changes for all the workers but it expands for just the worker I click on. What could be the reason behind this?

Comment: What do you mean by 'the button changes'? I'm not able to visualize how that looks different than expected.

Comment: Please see the update. Instead of using toggle as the button text, I am trying to use the button as <button @click="toggle(worker.id)">{{showSection?' read less':'...'}}</button>. So the issue here is when I click on the button for any particular worker to expand the services it, it expands the services for the particular worker but changes the button text for all other workers also. I hope I am able to explain the problem.

Comment: I see. This should use the same id based logic rather than assuming true/false, e.g. `{{showSection === worker.id ?' read less':'...'}}`

Comment: Is there a way that once the services of a particular worker are expanded, I can expand the services of another worker. Because right now when I click on another worker the services of already expanded worker closes.

Comment: Yes, that was the idea of instead of having just one value in the variable `showSection` it be an array of displayed worker.id's. Then checking is `showSection.includes(worker.id)` and toggling has to add or remove the worker.id depending on if it's already contained.

Comment: Can you help me achieve that?

Comment: Checking if an array contains a value is like `showSections.includes(workerId)`. Removing a value is like `this.showSections = this.showSections.filter(id => id !== workerId)` to keep everything except `workerId`.

Comment: I tried my best But I couldn't achieve it. Please can you update the answer plz.